# PM2 can't reach port:80 only after autostart on server reboot

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have a node.js express app running on an Ubuntu 21.04 server.
I run the app with pm2 with a non root user, the app listens on ports 80 and 443, I had the error `Error: bind EACCES null:80`.
As mentionned in the [pm2 documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/#listening-on-port-80-wo-root), I performed all instructions for ports 80 and 443 and it works like a charm.
I also ran `pm2 save` and `pm2 startup systemd` **to make the app autostart when server reboot**.

But when the server reboot:
`pm2 list` shows myApp with an online status, but I encounter again the error: `Error: bind EACCES null:80` and the app is not working.

Then if I `pm2 kill` and `pm2 start myApp` again, then it works well...

Do you know why on server reboot the pm2 starts not well but if I start it manually it's ok?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [this post from the pm2 team on github](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3165#issuecomment-391399136), this is because of the authbind when [listening on port 80](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/#listening-on-port-80-wo-root).

Edit the config file created by the [pm2 startup procedure](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/) (the file should be at `/etc/systemd/system/pm2-<your-user>.service`, and add `/usr/bin/authbind --deep`  at the begining of the 3 commands ExecStart, ExecReload and ExecStop, leaving the rest of the command. For example in my config file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/authbind --deep /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/usr/bin/authbind --deep /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/usr/bin/authbind --deep /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill
```

Then app auto-restarts well with non root user after server reboot!